# What comes after Eclipse Galileo?

Tags: eclipse

What's the name of the Eclipse release for 2010?  I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: All these worlds are yours, except NetBeans. Attempt no landings there.

Comment: Much more interesting is the question what happens the moment the names of moons are all used. Is Eclipse considered stabel then without any further need of change? Or will the go on to moon 63 and call all the versions Eclipse Jupiter XXII Eclipse Jupiter XXIII ...

Comment: @Janusz: Galileo isn't even a Jupiter moon, in case you haven't noticed. Neither is Helios...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Eclipse 3.6 **Helios**](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipse.org-planning-council/msg01622.html)

You have here the [preliminary plan](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=eclipse). Check also the (for now empty) [wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Helios).

Comment: What's beautiful about the preliminary plan is that it mentions no substantial new features or specific work items, yet has the milestone dates set in stone.

"We don't know what we're gonna do but we're gonna do it on time."

Answer (score 3):

The next big thing is Eclipse 4.* which for now is still just known as E4. I don't think they made the name public yet.

Comment: E4 really really has me interested

Comment: Can you summarize the big features for E4?

Comment: Endless reruns of Big Brother and Hollyoaks